# Check if the struct is in array

Tags: ios, arrays, macos, swift, struct

I have the following Structure:

```
struct MyStrict {
    let prop1: String
    let prop2: [String: NSData]
    let prop3: [String]

    init (prop11: String, prop22: [String : NSData], prop33: [String]) {
        prop1 = prop11
        prop2 = prop22
        prop3 = prop33
    }
}
```

The instance structure is placed in the Array. What I need to do is to find if the structure with those properties are in the array or not. I need to compare data.

Something like this:

```
var arr = [MyStrict]()

var str1 = MyStrict(prop11: "test1", prop22: ["aa": NSData()], prop33: ["bb"])
arr.append(str1)

var str2 = MyStrict(prop11: "test2", prop22: ["bb": NSData()], prop33: ["cc"])
arr.append(str2)

var str3 = MyStrict(prop11: "test3", prop22: ["cc": NSData()], prop33: ["dd"])
arr.append(str3)

var str4 = MyStrict(prop11: "test1", prop22: ["aa": NSData()], prop33: ["bb"]) // has the same data as str1
arr.append(str4)
```

As you can see the `str1` and `str4` have the same data. So `str4` should not be add to the Array.

My question what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the protocol Equatable to your Struct

```
struct MyStrict: Equatable {
...
}
```

Then you have to add the == operator under the class like this :

```
func == (lhs: MyStrict, rhs: MyStrict) -> Bool {
  if lhs.prop1 == rhs.prop1 && lhs.prop3 == rhs.prop3 && lhs.prop2 == rhs.prop2 {
    return true
}

  return false
}
```

Now, to know if your struct is already in the array you just have to use this :

```
if contains(arr, str4) == true {
  println("already in")
} else {
  println("Not in")
}
```

Comment: Or just `if contains(arr, str4) ... `

Comment: I edited the answer. Contains fits the question needs better.